# Retrieve Specific Data from Session List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I stored a List in a Session.
I am able to get the Username from List by accessing `userInfo[1]`.
After stored in Session, I am unable to do it with `Session["userInfo"][1]`.

It gave me an error that

> "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object.

Any idea/hints for me about this?

```
List<string> userInfo = new List<string>();
userInfo.Add(UserID);
userInfo.Add(Username);
userInfo.Add(Role);
Session[userInfo"] = userInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it as `List` first because by default Session will return as type object, like this:

```
var theUserInfo = Session["userInfo"] as List<string>;

// checking if it is indeed List of string
if(theUserInfo != null)
{
   // do something here with the list..
}
```

or you can implicitly cast like this:

```
userInfo = (List<string>) Session["userInfo"]
```

as additional notes, if you Explicitly cast the object, there's a chance that you can get an `Invalid Cast Exception`. So, I recommend you to use "classic" approach that use `as` syntax, because it will return null rather than throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now with var theUserInfo = Session["mon_user"] as List<string>;

Any idea on not to declare a theUserInfo to access it?

Comment: yes, you can explicit cast it. see my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have to cast it to `List<string>` first.

```
((List<string>)Session["userInfo")[1]
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in more of an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)